# Reading from postgres using Akka Streams 2.4.2 and Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, akka-stream, slick-3.0

Trying out the newly minted Akka Streams. It seems to be working except for one small thing - there's no output.

I have the following table definition:

```
case class my_stream(id: Int, value: String)

class Streams(tag: Tag) extends Table[my_stream](tag, "my_stream") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def value = column[String]("value")
  def * = (id, value) <> (my_stream.tupled, my_stream.unapply)
}
```

And I'm trying to output the contents of the table to stdout like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Subscriber")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val strm = TableQuery[Streams]
  val db = Database.forConfig("pg-postgres")

  try{
    var src = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(strm.result))
    src.runForeach(r => println(s"${r.id},${r.value}"))(materializer)
  } finally {
    system.shutdown
    db.close
  }
}
```

I have verified that the query is being run by configuring debug logging. However, all I get is this:

```
08:59:24.099 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - pg-postgres - is starting.
08:59:24.428 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - pg-postgres - is closing down.
```

Comment: My guess is that because you ignore the return value from `runForeach` you don't see that it is a future, and as such the stream will be shut down immediately by system.shutdown and then db.close, before the processing has had a chance to execute (Akka Streams are async).

Comment: Also, you don't need to make the ActorMaterializer implicit if you're passing it explicitly, and vice versa. :)

Comment: Thanks, @ViktorKlang. Will you submit an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is that Akka Streams is asynchronous and `runForeach` returns a Future which will be completed once the stream completes, but that Future is not being handled and as such the `system.shutdown` and `db.close` executes immediately instead of after the stream completes.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone searching this very same issue but in MySQL, take into account that you should enable the driver stream support "manually":

```
def enableStream(statement: java.sql.Statement): Unit = {
  statement match {
    case s: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl => s.enableStreamingResults()
    case _ =>
  }
}

val publisher = sourceDb.stream(query.result.withStatementParameters(statementInit = enableStream))
```

Source: http://www.slideshare.net/kazukinegoro5/akka-streams-100-scalamatsuri

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using @ViktorKlang answer and just wrapped the run with an `Await.result`. I also found an alternative answer [in the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala/stream-integrations.html#Integrating_with_Reactive_Streams) which demonstrates using the reactive streams publisher and subscriber interfaces:

The `stream` method returns a `DatabasePublisher[T]` and `Source.fromPublisher` returns a `Source[T, NotUsed]`. This means you have to attach a subscriber instead of using `runForEach` - according to the [release notes](http://akka.io/news/2016/02/17/akka-2.4.2-released.html) `NotUsed` is a replacement for `Unit`. Which means nothing gets passed to the `Sink`.

Since Slick implements the reactive streams interface and not the Akka Stream interfaces you need to use the `fromPublisher` and `fromSubscriber` integration point. That means you need to implement the `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber[T]` interface.

Here's a quick and dirty `Subscriber[T]` implementation which simply calls `println`:

```
class MyStreamWriter extends org.reactivestreams.Subscriber[my_stream] {
  private var sub : Option[Subscription] = None;

  override def onNext(t: my_stream): Unit = {
    println(t.value)
    if(sub.nonEmpty) sub.head.request(1)
  }

  override def onError(throwable: Throwable): Unit = {
    println(throwable.getMessage)
  }

  override def onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription): Unit = {
    sub = Some(subscription)
    sub.head.request(1)
  }

  override def onComplete(): Unit = {
    println("ALL DONE!")
  }
}
```

You need to make sure you call the `Subscription.request(Long)` method in `onSubscribe` and then in `onNext` to ask for data or nothing will be sent or you won't get the full set of results.

And here's how you use it:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Subscriber")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val strm = TableQuery[Streams]
  val db = Database.forConfig("pg-postgres")

  try{
    val src = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(strm.result))
    val flow = src.to(Sink.fromSubscriber(new MyStreamWriter()))
    flow.run()
  } finally {
    system.shutdown
    db.close
  }
}
```

I'm still trying to figure this out so I welcome any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this still pull all rows into memory?